# How to install two versions of an app

Tags: android, package

is there a simple way to have installed two version of the app on the same android Phone?

Im updating a old web app to a native android app. For testing purpose it would be great if we could have both installed at the same time on the same device.

It would be great to rename the update just temporary.

If I rename the package name in the AndroidManifest, then also R will be renamed and I have to reorganize the imports etc.

Is it possible to do a simple rename only somewhere in the AndroidManifest without changing a single line of code (even not with eclipse / android studio refactoring mechanism).

I have tried to mark my native app as library project and to include it in a new Android Project with another package name. But I will get trouble with this approach, for instance with actionbar sherlock:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/actionbarsherlock/R$attr;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/actionbarsherlock/R$attr;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new gradle build system you could create new [build type](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types) and then just add `packageNameSuffix`to it. This will add suffix to your package name but everything else stays the same.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        packageNameSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

Comment: damn, that would be a nice solution, but unfortunately I do not use gradle right now. I really have to migrate to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way if you want to do it temporarily.  You need to modify the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Find the line that looks like this:

manifest package="com.example.myapp"

and change it to something like:

"com.example.myapp.debug"

Comment: If I do so, than also R will be removed in com.example.myapp.debug.R and the imports need to be changed

Comment: If you use Android Tools -> Rename Application Package as mentioned by  Benito Bertoli below, Eclipse will prompt you to accept all the possible changes related to renaming.

Comment: Yes I know, but I do not want to change any single line of code, because I do not want to commit the changes into git. In 3 weeks (after some testing) I will rename it back to the original package name. I hoped there would be a simple xml attribute where I can specify that ...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way other than changing the application package name, but it's fairly easy.

In Eclipse, right-click your project and select Android Tools > Rename Application Package.